# Strange behavior of Lucene SpanishAnalyzer class with accented words

Tags: lucene, analyzer, diacritics, stemming

I'm using the SpanishAnalyzer class in Lucene 3.4. When I want to parse accented words, I'm having a strange result. If I parse, for example, these two words: "comunicación" and "comunicacion", the stems I'm getting are "comun" and "comunicacion". If I instead parse "maratón" and "maraton", I'm getting the same stem for both words ("maraton").

So, at least in my opinion, it's very strange that the same word, "comunicación", gives different results depending on it is accented or not. If I search the word "comunicacion", I should get the same result regardless of whether it's accented or not.

The code I'm using is the next one:

```
SpanishAnalyzer sa = new SpanishAnalzyer(Version.LUCENE_34);
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_34, "content", sa);
String str = "comunicación";
String str2 = "comunicacion";
System.out.println("first: " + parser.parse(str)); //stem = comun
System.out.println("second: " + parser.parse(str2)); //stem = comunicacion
```

The solution I've found to be able to get every single word that shares the stem of "comunicacion", accented or not, is to take off accents in a first step, and then parse it with the Analyzer, but I don't know if it's the right way.

Please, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check what tokenizer & tokenfilters SpanishAnalyzer uses? There is something called ASCIIFoldingFilter. Try placing it before the StemFilter. It will remove the accents